# Load specific thumbnail thumbnail using xml?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, youtube-api

I've managed to load a thumbnail from youtube, but how can I choose one of the six thumbnails that exist per video?

```
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/default.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:02:42' yt:name='default'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/mqdefault.jpg' height='180' width='320' yt:name='mqdefault'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/hqdefault.jpg' height='360' width='480' yt:name='hqdefault'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:21' yt:name='start'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:02:42' yt:name='middle'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dTI0KDuQl_4/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:04:03' yt:name='end'/>
```

For example I want the third one (hqdefault).

I tried the following using mwfeedparser:

```
else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/feed/entry/media:group/media:thumbnail"]) {
                    NSArray *urlArray = [currentElementAttributes objectForKey:@"url"];                   
                    item.thumbnail = urlArray;  
                    processed = YES;
                }
```

And in my view controller I entered:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[item.thumbnail objectAtIndex:3] URLString]]];
    cell.videoThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

But it keeps crashing :/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try async image which useful for download images in background.....
the below link may be give you some idea for download your images from background one by one....

http://www.geekygoodness.com/2009/09/13/a-simple-cocoa-asynchronous-image-loader-class-to-use-in-your-iphone-app/

hope,this help you

Comment: Thank you i'll check it out. Would that also improve the performance of the scrolling?

Comment: So I checked it out and this won't work for me since I'm parsing more than just an image I'm parsing descriptions, titles, etc. I've managed to pull in a thumbnail it's just kind of blurry, since my uiimageview is 90x120, and so is the default image. I would like to pull the third thumbnail, so it would look crisp...

Comment: yes your scrolling will very smooth and here if you want to download image with deffirent size then you must manage size with your own different method but if you follow async image then it is very useful to you and also your app display attractive and smooth.

Comment: I actuallly found a way to load the thumbnail of my choice since they each have a predictable format! I'm thinking of trying out SBWebImage... would you recommend that? BTW I am loading my images as of right now using asynch, but it's really slow scrolling.

Comment: yes but i added my custom code for fast download image,for your requirement you must edit the code and also it is too easy its work which you want,just try to edit code with your requirement dear....     :)